# .htaccess rewrite content to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following folders structure on my web server:

[image: Folder structure]

I need some rewrite rules:

1. When I visit `http://testdomain1.com/` I need to set `/pages/testdomain1.com/` as the root directory to display content from this dir.

   Similarly, `http://testdomain2.com/` root folder is `/pages/testdomain2.com/` etc..
2. When the requested URL has the `la` var - I need to rewrite to landing directory.

   Example:
   `http://testdomain1.com/?la=template1` - set `/lands/template1/` as root dir

I have some issue with my current `.htaccess` (for first task):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?testdomain1.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ pages/%{HTTP_HOST}/index.html [L]
```

Rewrite rule works, but all assets data (js, css) don't work (404 not found).
How can I set the right rules?

Comment: Where do the two domains `testdomain1.com` and `testdomain2.com` currently point to? Both to the `www` subdirectory? "I need rewrite to land directory" - It doesn't really make sense to rewrite to a "directory" - you should rewrite to a "file". What is the file in that directory that handles the request? (If you rewrite to the directory then I assume you are relying on mod_dir issuing an internal subrequest for the DirectoryIndex?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... but all assets data (js,css) don't work (404 not found). How can I set right rules?

This is most probably caused by using relative URL paths to your assets. You need to "fix" your URL paths to be root-relative or absolute. This is not something that should be fixed in `.htaccess`, your rewrite is otherwise OK.

See [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack, relating to the use of relative URL paths to static assets when using URL rewriting:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?testdomain1.com$
> RewriteRule ^(/)?$ pages/%{HTTP_HOST}/index.html [L]
> ```

This only rewrites requests for the root, ie. `testdomain1.com/`. And not `testdomain1.com/foo` - is that intentional?

> I need to have access to any page (`example.com/page.html`) not only `index.html`.

If by that you mean that a request of the form `http://testdomain1.com/foo` should be rewritten to `/pages/testdomain1.com/foo`, then you would need to change the above to something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^la=[\w-]+
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?(testdomain1\.com)$
RewriteRule !^pages/ pages/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Note that this rewrites *everything*, including CSS, JS and images.

The first condition (`RewriteCond` directive) excludes URLs that contain the `la` URL parameter. (These URLs are handled below.)

This also fixes a bug in your existing directive, whereby a request for the www subdomain (eg. `www.testdomain1.com`) would have resulted in an incorrect rewrite. The `%1` backreference in the *substitution* string contains the domain being requested - less an optional `www` subdomain. (I assume you don't have a subdirectory `www.testdomain1.com`?) Although, arguably, you should already be canonicalising the www/non-www earlier in the config file.

(Remember to escape literal dots.)

**UPDATE:**

> i tried to use this case for multiple domains, not only for `testdomain1.com`. So i need change `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?testdomain1.com$` part. I just tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` but don't working.

For multiple domains, you can either:

- Duplicate the above code block for each domain and change the `testdomain1.com` domain in the second condition.
- If this applies to just 3 domains then you can use *alternation* in the second condition, to match any of the 3 domains. For example:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?(testdomain1\.com|testdomain2\.com|testdomain3\.com)$
  ```
- If this should apply to any domain, then make the regex more general to match any domain. For example:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www.)?([a-z0-9.-]+?)\.?$
  ```

> 2) When request URL have "la" var - I need rewrite to land directory.
>   Example: `http://testdomain1.com/?la=template1` - set `/lands/template1/` as root dir

As mentioned in my comment, you probably shouldn't be rewriting to a directory. It is not the directory that handles the request, but ultimately a file. By rewriting to a directory I assume you are relying on mod_dir issuing an internal subrequest for the directory index document (as specified by the `DirectoryIndex` directive). For the sake of this example, I will assume the directory index is `index.php`.

This would need to go *before* the above rewrite, since it is more specific:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^la=([\w-]+)
RewriteRule ^$ /lands/%1/index.php [L]
```

`%1` (as opposed to `$1`) is a backreference to the captured pattern in the last matched *CondPattern*. The regex `[\w-]+` restricts the `la` parameter value to the characters `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `_` and `-`. The `la` parameter must also be the first URL parameter.

Comment: Hi Mr White! Your solution for p.2 works well, thanks, but in first case I need to have access to any page (example.com/page.html) not only index.html

Comment: So, `example.com/page.html` should rewrite to `/pages/example.com/page.html`? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, but now second rule (with "la" var) does not work:

URL `/pages/testdomain1.com/lands/test1/index.php` not found

Comment: Ah yes, the first rule would catch the request as well. I've updated my answer to add another condition, to exclude URLs from the first rule that contain the `la` URL parameter.

Comment: Thank you so mutch. And last moment, i tried to use this case for multiple domains, not only for testdomain1.com. So i need change `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?testdomain1.com$` part. I just tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` but don't working..

Comment: Yes, for multiple domains, you would need to modify the condition (`RewriteCond` directive) that checks the `Host` header (`HTTP_HOST` server variable). `REQUEST_URI` contains the URL-path only. I've updated my answer.